# Use IntelliJ Idea to Debug ActionScript Running in a Browser?

Tags: actionscript-3, intellij-idea

I have an ActionScript project that runs inside of another swf (embedded on an HTML page) so I can't use the 'Debug' option in IntelliJ's menu.  Is there a way to connect the IDE's debugger to the browser so I can use breakpoints and such?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Flash Remote Debug option, just create a new remote debug profile
then hit debug and intelliJ waits until a swf debug file is launched on your computer it can be with a standalone player or plugin in a browser. both of them need to be debugger versions and your swf needs also to allow debugging (in Flash CC default does not accept debugging you need to change the publish settings).

I use this method to debug with IntelliJ an swf launched inside Flash CC hitting cmd+enter.

Maybe it works when you load and swf inside another.